# How to use a separated template in ui-router?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I have an angular app that uses **ui-router** for view routing.

I have a master template with all my layout, and inside that I have my ui-view like below:

```
<div class="content" ui-view>
<div>
```

and my routes in app:

```
 app.config(["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $stateProvider
            .state("customers", {
                url: "/customers",
                templateUrl: "app/customers/tpl.html",
                controller: "Customers as vm"
            });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/dashboard");

    }]);
```

In the code above, the templateUrl is injected in my content, as usual.

Now, I have a login page that uses a completely different layout of my app. Is there any way to tell ui-router to use a custom layout? How to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make all other states share a common parent state. This parent state may have an empty string for a url.

The following snippet should two ways to implement parent states. The options are either to name the state `parent.child`. The other way is to explicitly mention the parent in the state definition.

```js
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp', [
  'ui.router'
]).

config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider.
  state('login', {  // The login state has no parent
    url: '/login',
    template: '<h1>Login</h1>'
  }).
  state('app', {
    url: '',
    abstract: true,
    template:
      '<h1>Default template</h1>' +
      '<a ui-sref="customers">Customers</a>' +
      '<br/>' +
      '<a ui-sref="app.dashboard">Dashboard</a>' +
      '<br/>' +
      '<a ui-sref="login">Login Page</a>' +
      '<div class="content" ui-view></div>'
  }).
  state('customers', {
    parent: 'app',  // app is the parent state of customers
    url: '/customers',
    template: '<h3>Customers Page</h3>'
  }).
  state('app.dashboard', {  // app is the parent state of dashboard
    url: '/dashboard',
    template: '<h3>Dashboard Page</h3>'
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/dashboard');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.14/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ui-view></div>
```

For more details see the [ui-router docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views).